# Determine the size of data in each partition in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Just wanted to know how to determine how much each topic partition in Kafka is taking up the space.. Using "kafka-consumer-groups.sh" we can determine the offset number but I wanted to know how much space data in each partition is taking..

Comment: It would be easier to use `df -h` on the actual brokers data directories to get this information

Answer (score 3):

Using the AdminClient, you can find the size of partitions (per replica) using [`describeReplicaLogDirs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeReplicaLogDirs-java.util.Collection-).

As mentioned, this is per replica so if the partitions have several replicas, you can either query them all or query only the leader depending how you want to count the size on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but in case anyone else is looking into this...

I didn't have any luck with describeReplicaLogDirs (mentioned above) but I may be using a different version of the library.

I had to determine if *any* of the partitions for a particular topic had any data and here's how I went about it:

```
    String topic = <topic searched for>;
    AdminClient kafkaAdminClient = AdminClient.create(<Kafka properties>);
    // From another question in SO
    List<Integer> brokers = kafkaAdminClient.describeCluster().nodes().get().stream()
                            .mapToInt(Node::id).boxed().collect(toList());

    // Get the descriptionLogDirs for all the topics partitions/replicas
    DescribeLogDirsResult replicaLogDirs = kafkaAdminClient.describeLogDirs(brokers);

    return replicaLogDirs.values().entrySet()         //Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, KafkaFuture<Map<String, LogDirInfo>>>>
                         .stream().map(t -> getMap(t.getValue()).values())
                         .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<LogDirInfo>
                         .map(t -> t.replicaInfos)    // Stream<Map<TopicPartition, ReplicaInfo>>
                         .anyMatch(a -> a.entrySet().stream()
                                         .filter(b -> b.getKey().topic().equals(topic) && b.getValue().size > 0L)
                                         .peek(n -> log.info("Found partition {} for topic {} with size {}", n.getKey().partition(), n.getKey().topic(), n.getValue().size))
                                         .findFirst().isPresent());
```

The above should be easily modifiable to return the size if required.